# How to manage BottomNavigationView backstack in Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack

I am using `navigation component` and `BottomNavigationView`, i am facing a problem, that is when i go to from `fragment` 1>2>5>4>3 and when i press back button i get `fragment` 1. I know this is the default behavior but i don't want this, i want to save them in `backstack` so when i press back button it should go to `fragment` 4 not 1. I have been  trying and searching but i couldn't find any solution. Can i put `fragment` manually into `backstack` in `kotlin`?

My code:

> activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           .......................
           .......................>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
               ................
               ................/>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/app_nav_host_fragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/app_nav"
                ..............
                ............../>
            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/app_bottom_nav_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_bottom"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
                ...........
                .........../>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> app_nav.xml

```
<navigation 
    ...........
    ...........
    android:id="@+id/app_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.instagram_clone.ui.HomeFragment"
        android:label="HomeFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home"/>
    .............
    .............
    .............
    .............
</navigation>
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        val bottomNavView = binding.appBottomNavView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.app_nav_host_fragment)

        bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As per the documentation on [onNavDestinationSelected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)) (the method that `setupWithNavController()` uses when selecting a MenuItem):

> By default, the back stack will be popped back to the navigation graph's start destination. Menu items that have `android:menuCategory="secondary"` will not pop the back stack.

So just add `android:menuCategory="secondary"` to each of the menu items used with your `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: And how to not put a fragment again into back stack that is already in it?

Comment: You'd need to set your own `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` after the call to `setupWithNavController` and do your own `navigate()` call, adding the `NavOptions` object with `setPopUpTo` the same destination you're navigating to, following the same pattern that [the code behind onNavDestinationSelected() does](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/navigation/navigation-ui/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.java#57) - there's no built in helper for that behavior.

Comment: I'm currently having the issue that nothing is popped. (with default setup)
If i navigate 1 > 2 > 3 and then press back, i get to 2. (on 2.1.0).

Comment: @cwiesner - sounds like you popped the start destination of your graph. You shouldn't do that (see the Principles of Navigation documentation and the docs there on Conditional Navigation)

Comment: oh thanks for the hint. I was using an onboarding fragment as start destination which called then the first destination in the bottom nav.  will need to turn that order around.

Comment: @ianhanniballake my start destination is splash screen and I navigate from splash to this screen with bottomNavigation. so if i do not popup my start destination, splashh screen will be always there. so what is the best practice to handle this problem?

Comment: @Askani here is how to not put a fragment again into back stack that is already in it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68779398/2425851

Comment: @SamanSattari I'm having the same problem as you. Were you able to figure out a way to solve the issue?