# Android clear backstack after reselecting Bottom Navigation tab

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-bottomnav

Using the newest [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation) with the `BottomNavigationView`, the `NavController` now saves and restores the states of tabs by default:

> As part of this change, the NavigationUI methods of onNavDestinationSelected(), BottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController() and NavigationView.setupWithNavController() now automatically save and restore the state of popped destinations, enabling support for multiple back stacks without any code changes. When using Navigation with Fragments, this is the recommended way to integrate with multiple back stacks.

This is great!  Now switching tabs gives you the last viewed stack.

But, if the user **reselects** a tab, say they've gone `Home -> Detail Page A -> Detail Page B`, then they select the `Home` tab expecting to go back to the default view, they still see `Detail Page B`.

It seems like part of the discussion was to handle the "reselecting a tab" behavior as mentioned in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773), but I can't figure out the recommended way for implementing this.

All that's included in the [NavigationAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) is:

```
val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)
bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

// Setup the ActionBar with navController and 3 top level destinations
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(R.id.titleScreen, R.id.leaderboard,  R.id.register)
    )
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

And this just restores the previous state, as noted in the release notes.

How can we check for tapping a nav bar item a second time and clear the back stack?

Comment: Is the solution working for all of your tabs?
Indeed, for me it is working only for the main tab.
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`BottomNavigationView` has its own method for handling reselection via [`setOnItemReselectedListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationBarView#setOnItemReselectedListener(com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.OnItemReselectedListener)) (or, when using an earlier version of the Material Design Library, the now deprecated [`setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView#setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener))).

`bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController` does not set this listener (as there is no Material specification for exactly what reselecting a tab should do), so you need to set it yourself:

```
val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)
bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

// Add your own reselected listener
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemReselectedListener { item ->
    // Pop everything up to the reselected item
    val reselectedDestinationId = item.itemId
    navController.popBackStack(reselectedDestinationId, inclusive = false)
}
```

Comment: Press on tabs: A->B->C->B->C, backstack will be: FragmentA->FragmentB->FragmentC->FragmentB->FragmentC

Comment: Thanks.
Is is possible to do the same effect when user select a new tab?

Indeed, with the new navigation version 2.4.0 the back stack of each tab is saved. 
Now I want to reset the backstack of each tab when I am leaving it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, sorry but this solution is not working for me.
It works only for the main tab but not for the others.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer got me started in the right direction. However, with the addition of multiple backstacks supported in Android navigation library 2.4.0, this is what ended up working for me:

```
val currentRootFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment)
val navHost = currentRootFragment as? NavHostFragment
val selectedMenuItemNavGraph = navHost?.navController?.graph?.findNode(menuItem.itemId) as? NavGraph?
selectedMenuItemNavGraph?.let { menuGraph ->
             navHost?.navController?.popBackStack(menuGraph.startDestinationId, false)
}
```

Comment: This should be the marked as the accepted answer

Comment: How to notify the fragment of the "refresh" in case of we reselect a tab where is already on the root of the sub-graph ?
Youtube app make a scroll-top of the recyclerview in this case

Comment: what is "main_fragment"?

Comment: The fragment which is your default Nav host. Usually its the "nav_host_container"

Answer (score 8):

Two methods come to the rescue here...

1. To update the selection after the item selected (item with back stack, with the latest version - 2.4.2, when there is a back stack present in top destination, selecting that item won't select the item first).

   `NavigationBarView.setOnItemSelectedListener {}`
2. To wait for the second click and perform popping of the back stack.

   `NavigationBarView.setOnItemReselectedListener {}`

Final code is ,

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment?
    val navController = navHostFragment?.navController

    mainBinding?.bottomNavigation?.apply {
        navController?.let { navController ->
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
                this,
                navController
            )
            setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
                NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                true
            }
            setOnItemReselectedListener {
                navController.popBackStack(destinationId = it.itemId, inclusive = false)
            }
        }
```

}

Hope this will help..

Comment: man you are the best. saved my project!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it both caches the previously loaded fragments and solves the issue of the retention of previous navigational queues

Answer (score 3):

This solution is made from [Callie's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71242413/11211963) and [ianhanniballake's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68779398/11211963) solution.

The behaviour is

1. `Home -> Detail Page A -> Detail Page B` then press `Home button` -> `Home`
2. `Home -> Detail Page A -> Detail Page B` then navigate to `Profile`
   then back to `Home` will show `Detail Page B` then `Home` pressed again
   will trigger 1 behaviour (so will go back to the `Home` screen.

   ```
   // navView = id of BottomNavigationView

   navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_container)
   // where nav_host_container is the id of the fragment which is your default Nav host. 

   binding.navView.setOnItemReselectedListener { menuItem ->              
      val selectedMenuItemNavGraph = 
          navController.graph.findNode(menuItem.itemId) as NavGraph              

      selectedMenuItemNavGraph.let { menuGraph ->           
          navController.popBackStack(menuGraph.startDestinationId, false)              
      }          
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use your own `setupWithNavController2` instead of `setupWithNavController` from `androidx.navigation.ui.BottomNavigationViewKt`

For ex.:

Added check of already selected item before to navigate :

```
   if (navController.popBackStack(item.itemId, false)) {
        return true
    }
```

See comments at `onNavDestinationSelected` , full code of `setupWithNavController2`:

```
fun BottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController2(navController: NavController) {
    val bottomNavigationView = this
    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
        onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
    }
    val weakReference = WeakReference(bottomNavigationView)
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(
        object : NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener {
            override fun onDestinationChanged(
                controller: NavController,
                destination: NavDestination,
                arguments: Bundle?
            ) {
                val view = weakReference.get()
                if (view == null) {
                    navController.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
                    return
                }
                val menu = view.menu
                var i = 0
                val size = menu.size()
                while (i < size) {
                    val item = menu.getItem(i)
                    if (matchDestination(destination, item.itemId)) {
                        item.isChecked = true
                    }
                    i++
                }
            }
        })

    // Add your own reselected listener
    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemReselectedListener { item ->
        // Pop everything up to the reselected item
        val reselectedDestinationId = item.itemId
        navController.popBackStack(reselectedDestinationId, false)
    }
}

fun onNavDestinationSelected(
    item: MenuItem,
    navController: NavController
): Boolean {
    val builder = NavOptions.Builder()
        .setLaunchSingleTop(true)
    if (navController.currentDestination?.parent?.findNode(item.itemId) is ActivityNavigator.Destination) {
        builder.setEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_enter_anim)
            .setExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
            .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
            .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.nav_default_pop_exit_anim)
    } else {
        builder.setEnterAnim(R.animator.nav_default_enter_anim)
            .setExitAnim(R.animator.nav_default_exit_anim)
            .setPopEnterAnim(R.animator.nav_default_pop_enter_anim)
            .setPopExitAnim(R.animator.nav_default_pop_exit_anim)
    }
    if (item.order and Menu.CATEGORY_SECONDARY == 0) {
        val findStartDestination = findStartDestination(navController.graph)
        if (findStartDestination != null) {
            builder.setPopUpTo(findStartDestination.id, false)
        }
    }
    val options = builder.build()
    //region The code was added to avoid adding already exist item
    if (navController.popBackStack(item.itemId, false)) {
        return true
    }
    //endregion
    return try {
        // TODO provide proper API instead of using Exceptions as Control-Flow.
        navController.navigate(item.itemId, null, options)
        true
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        false
    }
}

fun findStartDestination(graph: NavGraph): NavDestination? {
    var startDestination: NavDestination? = graph
    while (startDestination is NavGraph) {
        val parent = startDestination
        startDestination = parent.findNode(parent.startDestination)
    }
    return startDestination
}

fun matchDestination(
    destination: NavDestination,
    @IdRes destId: Int
): Boolean {
    var currentDestination: NavDestination? = destination
    while (currentDestination?.id != destId && currentDestination?.parent != null) {
        currentDestination = currentDestination.parent
    }
    return currentDestination?.id == destId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to show bottom navigation bar only for `R.id.titleScreen, R.id.leaderboard,  R.id.register` fragments, for others it should be hidden and they should have just the toolbar with back button