# Reselect operation on Bottom Naviation bar android with naviagtion component

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation

I have a bottom navigation bar which is connected with navHost and is configured using the following code:

```
    Val navHostFragment =supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    val bottomNavBar = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomBar)
    setupWithNavController(bottomNavBar, navController)
```

I have 4 fragments now when I switch to 2nd fragment(by clicking on 2nd icon in the bottom navigation bar) and then I navigate to another fragment which is linked to the 2nd fragment. When I click on the back button I switch to 2nd fragment.

All good till far.

**The problem is:** I want to go back to 2nd fragment from the opened fragment when I reselect the same icon in the bottom navigation bar

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with the help of this thread. If someone is facing the same issue, check this out:

[Android clear backstack after reselecting Bottom Navigation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68777836/android-clear-backstack-after-reselecting-bottom-navigation-tab)

I have integrated a better solution which lets you have animations too when switching from one fragment to another.

```
val id = navController.currentDestination?.id
        when (id) {
            R.id.detailedTransactionAnalysis -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_detailedTransactionAnalysis_to_MainScreen)
            }
            R.id.detailedCategoryTransactionsFragment -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_detailedCategoryTransactionsFragment_to_MainScreen)
            }
            R.id.addTransaction -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_addTransaction_to_Stats)
            }
        }
        navController.popBackStack(reselectedDestinationId, inclusive = false)
```

It works totally fine.