# Android Navigation Bar: How do I go to the main fragment when I select an item in the navigation bar again?

Tags: android, kotlin

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68777836/14519908) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73698804/14519908) which perfectly describes the behavior I need  navigation bar.

> The behaviour is
>
> `Home` -> `Detail Page A` -> `Detail Page B` then press `Home` button -> `Home`
>
> `Home` -> `Detail Page A` -> `Detail Page B` then navigate to `Profile` then
> back to `Home` will show `Detail Page B` then `Home` pressed again will
> trigger 1 behaviour (so will go back to the `Home` screen.

Code:

```kotlin
navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_container)
// where nav_host_container is the id of the fragment which is your default Nav host. 

binding.navView.setOnItemReselectedListener { menuItem ->              
   val selectedMenuItemNavGraph = 
       navController.graph.findNode(menuItem.itemId) as NavGraph              

   selectedMenuItemNavGraph.let { menuGraph ->           
       navController.popBackStack(menuGraph.startDestinationId, false)              
   }          
}
```

But when I tried to execute it, I got an error:

```
androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator$Destination cannot be cast to androidx.navigation.NavGraph
```

This is because `navController.graph.findNode(menuItem.itemId)` returns type `NavDestination`

How can this problem be solved differently?